# Can IPs be trusted inside a VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip-spoofing, openvpn

## Question

I have several linux clients connected to an OpenVPN server. Each client is given a persistent IP based on their [X509 Common Name](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40026/openssl-x509-whats-the-significance-of-cn-common-name). **Can I trust these IPs ?**

## Context

I have *Client1* and *Client2* connected to *Server*, all of them in an OpenVPN network:

[image: Network diagram - Created with draw.io]

I'd like to set up a NFS share to allow *Client1* (exclusively) to access to some files on *Server*. [The TLDP page about NFS and security](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/security.html) states that the IP whitelist in `/etc/export` is "*not terribly secure*". Does this still hold true inside a VPN ? More precisely, **is it possible for an attacker to spoof or take over *Client1*'s IP address** in a way that could allow access to the NFS share :

- if he owns a copy of *Client2*'s credentials?
- if he has root access to *Client2*?
- if he has physical access to *Client2*?

## Specifics

*(feel free to assume different software versions, configurations and/or encryption levels if you need to)*

- OpenVPN version is `2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu`
- The config file at `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` contains, among other lines:

  ```
  cipher AES-256-CBC
  client-config-dir ccd
  ```

  And the `ccd` folder contains a file for each client, containing this one line:

  ```
  ifconfig-push 10.20.1.N 10.20.0.1
  ```

  with `N` the ID of the client (1 or 2 here)
- `ccd-exclusive` is not enabled in the config file
- Signature algorithm is SHA1 with RSA encryption
- `/etc/exports` will allow a single IP to access the share :

  ```
  /some/dir 10.20.1.1(ro,all_squash,sync,subtree_check)
  ```

*Note: Please point out any other problem with my setup in the comments of the question. I will definitely look into it, but for the sake of leaving an usable artifact let's keep this thread about IP spoofing. Thank you very much for your time!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is since your using the same system as VPN endpoint and NFS share, its possible to 'spoof' the allowed ip address on the other side (e.g the public line of the server) unless mitigated through other means. (the NFS service has no idea that a specific IP should be on a specific interface)

The second is that if 1 of the machines is compromised in any way, it can be utilized as a relay for IP spoofing (Client2 can be setup than as a 'hop' between the attacker and the server spoofing Client1's IP in the process)

This is a hard to implement scenario, but doable for profesional attackers. (they have to find client1's IP for example) and if you limit NFS to only accept connectinos through openVPN, and at the same time employ a proper Intrusion detection. than the 'ip' filter can suffice for limiting the connection to only client1.