# Can you create an OpenSSL certificate with non-English field values?

Tags: certificates, openssl

My requirement is statename, countryname, CommonName should be in language other than English. e.g. Chinese . Is it possible to create such certificate?

Comment: My guess is yes based on information in http://security.stackexchange.com/a/40048/16960 , but I'm not sure and it's hard for me to appropriately research on my phone; maybe this serves as a good starting point for someone else.

Comment: Try these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478452/how-to-create-csr-with-utf8-subject-in-openssl, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598872/how-to-create-ssl-certificate-with-unicode-characters-in-the-organization-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create OpenSSL certificate with non-ASCII characters by using the -utf8 option.

In order to get a certificate for a public key, you create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) that contains the information to be certified, such as the Distinguished Name and Common Name, Organization, City, State, Country and Contact information.

When creating a CSR, OpenSSL interprets any text you enter as ASCII. If you try to enter non-ASCII characters (such as Chinese), the certificate will contain 'random' characters rather than the text you tried to enter.

However, it is possible to change this behaviour using the **-utf8** option (see [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Certificate_Request_.2F_pkcs10_.2F_req)):

```
openssl req -new -utf8 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -out csr.pem
```

In this case, the information entered is interpreted as UTF8, allowing you to enter Chinese characters in the interactive dialog asking for the Common Name, State, City, etc.